# How to retrieve from gallery and display in GridView?

Tags: android-studio, gridview, arraylist, uri, android-gallery

I have this project at school, and I have to design an application which allows the user to file a report that will be further analysed by the authorities.

I want him to be able to upload some images from the camera in order to demonstrate that what he is complaining about is real and I want the selected images to appear in the gridview inside the ADD_REPORT layout.

See image below:

[image]

I have seen so many different implementations but i do not quite understand when, where or why i should use a GridViewAdapter or a Image Adapter and how do i make the array list of images appear in the gridview.

I have the following main class corresponding the layout from the image:

```
public void ClickAddImagesFromGallery(View view) {
        Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        //where do we find the data??
        File pictureDirectory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        String pictureDirectoryPath = pictureDirectory.getPath();
        //get a Uri representation
        Uri data = Uri.parse(pictureDirectoryPath);
        //set data and type
        photoPickerIntent.setDataAndType(data, "image/*");


        //we will invoke this activity and get sth back from it
        startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE) {
                //universal resource indicator, the image's address
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                //declare a stream to read the image data from the storage environment
                try {
                    InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImageUri);
                    Bitmap imageBitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);

                    //gridView.setAdapter();

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to open image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //de completat
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_new_report);

        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.id_spinner_departments);
        spinner.setPrompt("Choose one");
        spinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<DepartmentResponsible>(this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, DepartmentResponsible.values()));
        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.ImageGridView);

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    }


Here i have the ImageAdapter class:

    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Image> items;


    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        context = c;
    }

    //---returns the number of images---
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    //---returns the ID of an item---
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    //---returns an ImageView view---
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            imageView = new ImageView(context);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(185, 185));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }
        //imageView.setImageResource();
        // obviously here i encounter an error ..
        //is this here even correct?
        //i am so confused
        return imageView;

    }

    }
Here is the xml containing the Gridview 




 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/nice_image"
    tools:context="ro.ase.pdm.incercare4.AddNewReport">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/id_addReport_textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="@string/id_addReport_textview"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.501"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.016" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:scrollbars="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvTitleReport"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/TitleTV"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
                tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/id_EditText_Title"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:maxLines="1"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvTitleReport"
                tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
                tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
                tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/id_textViewDescription"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/DescriptionTV"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/id_EditText_Title"
                tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
                tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="274dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/id_Description_EditText"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="43dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:digits="0123456789"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:maxLength="10"
                android:maxLines="1"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/id_textViewDescription"
                tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
                tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
                tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/id_textViewDepartments"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Choose department"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"

    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/id_Description_EditText"
                tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
                tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="274dp" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/id_spinner_departments"
                style="@style/SpinnerAsEditText"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="@android:drawable/btn_default"
                android:prompt="@string/spinner_title"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/id_textViewDepartments"
                tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
                tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
                tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />

            <GridView
                android:id="@+id/ImageGridView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="128dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:columnWidth="100dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
                android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:numColumns="3"
                android:rowCount="2"
                android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/id_spinner_departments"
                tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
                tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
                tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_adaugarePoza"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:onClick="ClickAddImagesFromGallery"
                android:text="Load Picture"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ImageGridView"
                tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
                tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
                tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnSubmitReport"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
                android:text="Submit Report"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_adaugarePoza"
                tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
                tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
                tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I also have an xml with grid_item_layout containing an ImageView but I am not sure how all these are functioning and is hard for me to identify why does my application crash after a select an image in the gallery instead of showing it in the gridview.

Thank you so much for the time you spend for this!